# How to Filter Category-wise Card Components in React.js?

Tags: reactjs

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { RiArrowDropDownLine } from "react-icons/ri";
import { CiSearch } from "react-icons/ci";
import YtCardComponent from './ytcard';

export default function Youtube() {
    const [dropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState(false);
    const [selectedCategory, setselectedCategory] = useState('All');
    const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState(''); 
    const [filteredCards, setFilteredCards] = useState([]); 

    const categories = [
        { id: 1, name: 'Downloader' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Converter' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Study' },
        { id: 3, name: 'All' },
        // Add more categories as needed
    ];

    const shouldShowAll = selectedCategory === 'All' && searchQuery.trim() !== '';

    return (
        <section className='text-center h-full'>
            <div className="px-4 py-8 text-center">
                <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight text-amber-400 xl:text-4xl max-sm:text-1xl">
                    All Necessary Tools in One Place
                </h2>
                <div className='flex flex-row'>
                    <p className="mt-4 ml-[50px] block max-w-3xl text-white font-semibold ">
                        There's a growing trend towards the use of digital tools and software across various industries. To cater to diverse user needs, We are offering customization and personalization options in their downloader and converter tools
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h2 className="text-2xl text-center font-bold tracking-tight text-amber-400 xl:text-4xl">
                Search Your Required Tool
            </h2>
            <div className='mt-6 ml-3'>
                
              <form className="flex">
                  <div className="relative">
                      <button 
                          id="dropdown-button-2" 
                          onClick={() => setDropdownOpen(!dropdownOpen)} 
                          className="flex-shrink-0 z-10 inline-flex items-center h-full py-2.5 px-4 text-sm font-medium text-center text-gray-500 bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-s-lg hover:bg-gray-200 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:focus:ring-gray-700 dark:text-white dark:border-gray-600" 
                          type="button"
                          style={{ width: '100px', minHeight: '36px' }} // Adjust width and height as needed
                      >
                          {selectedCategory}
                          <RiArrowDropDownLine/>
                      </button>
                      {dropdownOpen && (
                          <div id="dropdown-search-city" className="z-10 bg-white divide-y divide-gray-100 rounded-lg shadow w-44 left-0 mt-1 absolute dark:bg-gray-700">
                              <ul className="py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200" aria-labelledby="dropdown-button-2">
                                  {filteredcategories.map(country => (
                                      <li key={country.id}>
                                          <button 
                                              type="button" 
                                              onClick={() => handleCountrySelect(country.name)} 
                                              className="inline-flex w-full px-4 py-2 text-sm text-black hover:bg-gray-100 dark:text-gray-200 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white" 
                                              role="menuitem"
                                          >
                                              {country.name}
                                          </button>
                                      </li>
                                  ))}
                              </ul>
                          </div>
                      )}
                  </div>
                  <div className="relative w-full ml-2">
                    <input 
                        type="search" 
                        id="location-search" 
                        className="block p-2.5 w-full z-30 text-sm text-gray-900 bg-gray-50 rounded-e-lg border-s-gray-50 border-s-2 border border-gray-300 focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-s-gray-700  dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:border-blue-500" 
                        placeholder="Search Tool" 
                        value={searchQuery} 
                        onChange={handleSearchChange} // Handle search input change
                        required
                    />
                    <button 
                        type="submit" 
                        className="absolute top-0 right-0 h-full p-2.5 text-sm font-medium text-white bg-amber-400 rounded-e-lg border border-blue-700 hover:bg-amber-500 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800"
                    >
                        <span className="sr-only">Search</span>
                        <CiSearch className='text-black'/>
                    </button>
                </div>

              </form>

            </div>

            {shouldShowAll && (
                <div className="mt-6 mx-auto max-w-3xl">
                   {filteredCards.map(card => (
                       <YtCardComponent key={card.id} {...card}/>
                   ))}
                </div>
            )}
        </section>
    );
}
```

I'm working on a React.js project where I have a collection of card components representing various tools. Each tool belongs to a specific category, and I want to implement filtering functionality based on these categories.

Here's a brief overview of my current setup:

I have an array of objects representing categories, each containing an id and name.
Each card component has properties such as id, title, description, and category.
I've implemented a search feature allowing users to filter cards based on a search query.
Now, I'm looking to enhance the filtering functionality to allow users to filter cards based on specific categories. I want to display cards belonging to the selected category or display all cards if no category is selected.

Could someone please guide me on how to implement category-wise filtering in React.js? Any suggestions, code examples, or pointers to relevant resources would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use the filter function from js, imho filteredCards does not need to be a state, rather be a variable derivated from your cards.
Here is the updated code.
For your search query, you should use deburr from lodash (or some equivalent) https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lodash-_-deburr-method/ for reference

```js
export default function Youtube({ cards }) {
    const [dropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState(false);
    const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState();
    const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");

    const filteredCards = cards.filter((card) => {
   const matchesSearchQuery = deburr(card.title.toLowerCase()).includes(deburr(searchQuery.toLowerCase()));
        const matchesCategory = selectedCategory
            ? card.category === selectedCategory.id
            : true;

        return matchesSearchQuery && matchesCategory;
    });

    const categories = [
        { id: 1, name: "Downloader" },
        { id: 2, name: "Converter" },
        { id: 3, name: "Study" },
    ];

    const handleSelectCategory = (category) => {
        setSelectedCategory(category);
        setDropdownOpen(false);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div className="mt-6 ml-3">
                <form className="flex">
                    <div className="relative">
                        <button
                            id="dropdown-button-2"
                            onClick={() => setDropdownOpen(!dropdownOpen)}
                            className="flex-shrink-0 z-10 inline-flex items-center h-full py-2.5 px-4 text-sm font-medium text-center text-gray-500 bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-s-lg hover:bg-gray-200 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:focus:ring-gray-700 dark:text-white dark:border-gray-600"
                            type="button"
                            style={{ width: "100px", minHeight: "36px" }}
                        >
                            {selectedCategory ? selectedCategory.name : "All"}
                            <RiArrowDropDownLine />
                        </button>
                        {dropdownOpen && (
                            <div
                                id="dropdown-search-city"
                                className="z-10 bg-white divide-y divide-gray-100 rounded-lg shadow w-44 left-0 mt-1 absolute dark:bg-gray-700"
                            >
                                <ul
                                    className="py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200"
                                    aria-labelledby="dropdown-button-2"
                                >
                                    {categories.map((category) => (
                                        <li key={category.id}>
                                            <button
                                                type="button"
                                                onClick={() =>
                                                    handleSelectCategory(
                                                        category
                                                    )
                                                }
                                                className="inline-flex w-full px-4 py-2 text-sm text-black hover:bg-gray-100 dark:text-gray-200 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white"
                                                role="menuitem"
                                            >
                                                {category.name}
                                            </button>
                                        </li>
                                    ))}
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        )}
                    </div>
                    <div className="relative w-full ml-2">
                        <input
                            type="search"
                            id="location-search"
                            className="block p-2.5 w-full z-30 text-sm text-gray-900 bg-gray-50 rounded-e-lg border-s-gray-50 border-s-2 border border-gray-300 focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-s-gray-700  dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:border-blue-500"
                            placeholder="Search Tool"
                            value={searchQuery}
                            onChange={handleSearchChange}
                            required
                        />
                        <button
                            type="submit"
                            className="absolute top-0 right-0 h-full p-2.5 text-sm font-medium text-white bg-amber-400 rounded-e-lg border border-blue-700 hover:bg-amber-500 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800"
                        >
                            <span className="sr-only">Search</span>
                            <CiSearch className="text-black" />
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            {filteredCards.length > 0 && (
                <div className="mt-6 mx-auto max-w-3xl">
                    {filteredCards.map((card) => (
                        <YtCardComponent key={card.id} {...card} />
                    ))}
                </div>
            )}
        </>
    );
}
```